# How to encrypt an API key if using oracalize for some API in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, oracles, external-api, oraclize

In my smart contract, I want to use the random.org API to generate a random number, but when publishing the verified source code I don't want anyone to see what API key I'm using. The [etheroll contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xece701c76bd00d1c3f96410a0c69ea8dfcf5f34e#code)  uses the random.org API and does this as follows:

```
bytes32 rngId = oraclize_query("nested", "[URL] ['json(https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke).result.random[\"serialNumber\",\"data\"]', '\\n{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"generateSignedIntegers\",\"params\":{\"apiKey\":${[decrypt] BLTr+ZtMOLP2SQVXx8GRscYuXv+3wY5zdFgrQZNMMY3oO/6C7OoQkgu3KgfBuiJWW1S3U/+ya10XFGHv2P7MB7VYwFIZd3VOMI/Os8o1uJCdGGZgpR0Dkm5QoNH7MbDM0wa2RewBqlVLFGoZX1PJC+igBPNoHC4=},\"n\":1,\"min\":1,\"max\":100,\"replacement\":true,\"base\":10${[identity] \"}\"},\"id\":1${[identity] \"}\"}']", gasForOraclize);
```

I'm confused how this is working - where does `decrypt` come from and, if this works, how do I get an encrypted version of my API key that I can use `decrypt` on like the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in detail in the Oracalize Docs in [Ethereum > Adavanced Topics > Encrypted Queries](http://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-advanced-topics-encrypted-queries)

You use a supplied python script to encrypt a string with Oracalize public key listed in that section and only Oracalize can decrypt it. You're limited to one encrypted query parameter only.

Comment: That is the answer, but the python encryption script provided by Oraclize doesn't like the public key the webpage provides https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27318/what-is-the-oraclize-public-key