# What is the Oraclize public key?

Tags: oracles

I am using Oraclize in a smart contract and want to encrypt my API key. According to http://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-advanced-topics-encrypted-queries there is a python script from Oraclize that is used to encrypt text (https://github.com/oraclize/encrypted-queries), and this command should encrypt "YOUR QUERY" for example:

```
python encrypted_queries_tools.py -e -p 044992e9473b7d90ca54d2886c7addd14a61109af202f1c95e218b0c99eb060c7134c4ae46345d0383ac996185762f04997d6fd6c393c86e4325c469741e64eca9 "YOUR QUERY"
```

Running that command I get this error:

> C:\Python27\encrypted-queries-master\encrypted-queries-master\tools>python
>   encrypted_queries_tools.py -e -p
>   044992e9473b7d90ca54d2886c7addd14a61109af202f1c95e218b0c99eb060c7134c4ae46345d0383ac996185762f04997d6fd6c393c86e4325c469741e64eca9
>   "YOUR QUERY" File "encrypted_queries_tools.py", line 100 print
>   "Please, provide a valid public key" Is the public key given on the
>   website incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you are trying to run is in fact for Python 2. You are trying to use Python 3 there, (as you stated on your github issue) and also based on the fact that the error message is due to the Python 2 formatted print statement. If you wish to use Python 3, you can use the following utility to convert the code seamlessly to be compatible with Python 3 - https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

If you have Python 2 available, you should be able to use that as well, just ensure all the modules it uses, are installed and available locally for you, you can use pip for this.